# (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: {:error, {:postgrex, {'no such file or directory', 'postgrex.app'}}} , when running 'mix ecto.migrate'

Tags: elixir, ecto

I am new to the Elixir, here's what my config file, and Repo. and a migration looks like

```
use Mix.Config

config :zeri, ecto_repos: [Zeri.Repo]

database_url = "postgresql://postgres:9835674725@localhost:5432/kaisa_db"
config :zeri, Zeri.Repo, url: database_url
```

```
defmodule Zeri.Repo do
  use Ecto.Repo,
    otp_app: :zeri,
    adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres
end
```

```
defmodule Zeri.Repo.Migrations.First do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    execute("CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS \"uuid-ossp\";", "")

    create(table(:users, primary_key: false))
      add :id, :uuid, primary_key: true, default: fragment("uuid_generate_v4()")
      add :username, :text, null: true

    end
  end
end
```

when running 'mix ecto.migrate' i'm getting the following error

```
** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: {:error, {:postgrex, {'no such file or directory', 'postgrex.app'}}}
    (ecto_sql 3.8.3) lib/ecto/migrator.ex:136: Ecto.Migrator.with_repo/3
    (ecto_sql 3.8.3) lib/mix/tasks/ecto.migrate.ex:141: anonymous fn/5 in Mix.Tasks.Ecto.Migrate.run/2
    (elixir 1.13.4) lib/enum.ex:2396: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
    (ecto_sql 3.8.3) lib/mix/tasks/ecto.migrate.ex:129: Mix.Tasks.Ecto.Migrate.run/2
    (mix 1.13.4) lib/mix/task.ex:397: anonymous fn/3 in Mix.Task.run_task/3
    (mix 1.13.4) lib/mix/cli.ex:84: Mix.CLI.run_task/2
```

Comment: have you added the postgrex adapter dependency?

Comment: Yeah, please post `deps` callback of your `mix.exs` file.

Comment: That was the issue, added  ```{:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"}``` in deps callback & it's working now. Thanks :)